Use INDIRECT with a Range From Another Sheet
Data is pulled from "Company News" sheet containing news data onto another sheet, "Company".  In the "Company" sheet, I use the following formula :
=IF(INDEX('Company News'!B$12:B$500,$E$23 + ROW(A1)-1="","",INDEX('Company News'!B$12:B$500,$E$23 + ROW(A1)-1))
The sheet names "Company" and "Company News" are templates and are duplicated and renamed with the actual company names as companies are added/deleted from the workbook.  Example: "Awesomeness", "Awesomeness News" ; "Money Pit", "Money Pit News"
The "Company" sheets have the company name in Cell B3; therefore, I am trying to make the formula dynamic by using the text (Company Name) in B3 in the formula.
I believe the use of the INDIRECT function is necessary and have tried solutions such as :
=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & B3 & " News" & "'!B12" & ":'" & B3 & " News" & "'!B500"),$E$23 + ROW(A1) - 1)="","",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & B3 & " News" & "'!B12" & ":'" & B3 & " News" & "'!B500"),$E$23 + ROW(A1) - 1))
This throws a #REF! error.  Thank you for any guidance.

As your first formula works, I believe the second formula could be as follows:
=IF(INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & B3 & " News'!B12:B500"),$E$23 + ROW(A1) - 1)="","",INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & B3 & " News'!B12:B500"),$E$23 + ROW(A1) - 1))

